# Get the customer ID from an order ID in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I want to get the "mycred" balance of a customer through the order while using WP ALL Export to export the customer balance based on orders to a spreadsheet. It's actually probably quite simple. I'm able to get the Order ID, but not the Customer ID

Here is what I'm doing to test if I can get the customer ID:

```
function get_customeruserid($value)
{
  global $woocommerce, $post;

  $order = new WC_Order($post->ID);
  $order_id = $order->get_order_number();

  $customer = new WC_Customer($post->ID);
  $user_id = $customer->get_ID();

  $value = $user_id;
  return $value;
}
```

This returns a 0.

However, I can get the order number easily enough by doing this:

```
function get_customerorderid($value)
{
  global $woocommerce, $post;

  $order = new WC_Order($post->ID);
  $order_id = $order->get_order_number();

  $value = $order_id;
  return $value;
}
```

This returns the customer's order number which is great, but only half the battle. I now want the Customer ID so I call call the mycred balance function to show their balance.

Any ideas? I'm a newbie at php and probably very bad.

Comment: You have multiple ways to do it…

Answer (score 39):

To get the User ID from the Order ID, you can use many ways, Here are 2 of them:
In WooCommerce 3.0+ you can use [`WC_Order` Class methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html) this way:

```
function get_customerorderid(){
    global $order, $post;

    if( ! is_a($order, 'WC_Order') ) {
        $order_id = $post->ID;

        // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    } else {
        $order_id = $order->id;
    }

    // Get the user ID from WC_Order methods
    $user_id = $order->get_user_id(); // or $order->get_customer_id();

    return $user_id;
}
```

Before WooCommerce 3.0 version, you can use [**`get_post_meta()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) function this way:

```
function get_customerorderid(){
    global $order, $post;

    if( ! is_a($order, 'WC_Order') ) {
        $order_id = $post->ID;
    } else {
        $order_id = $order->id;
    }

    // Get the user ID
    $user_id = get_post_meta($order_id, '_customer_user', true);

    return $user_id;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

For those who want to specifically add the customer mycred balance from an ORDER into the CSV sheet within WP All Export here is the bit of code I used.
Thank you for your help getting it solved.

While editing an ORDER export in WP ALL EXPORT, add a new data object and click on it and "*Export the value returned by a PHP function*" then add the following function in the code editor:

```
function all_export_mycred($balance)
{
    global $woocommerce, $post;

    $order = new WC_Order($post->ID);
    $user_id = $order->get_user_id( );

    $balance = mycred_get_users_balance( $user_id );

            return $balance;

    }
```

Then make sure to add the "all_export_mycred" to the php return field.