# Add custom user email to CC for specific Woocommerce email notification

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, email-notifications, cc

In Woocommerce I try to customize the code [from this thread](https://jessepearson.net/2016/10/adding-bcc-emails-woocommerce/#comment-2813) to add a custom email as "CC" email address in customer completed order email notification:

```
/**
 * Function adds a BCC header to emails that match our array
 * 
 * @param string $headers The default headers being used
 * @param string $object  The email type/object that is being processed
 */
    function add_cc_to_certain_emails( $headers, $object ) {
    // email types/objects to add cc to
    $cc_email = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'order_cc_email', true ); // MY CUSTOM CODE
    $add_cc_to = array(
        'customer_completed_order', // Customer Processing order from WooCommerce
    );
    // if our email object is in our array
    if ( in_array( $object, $add_cc_to ) ) {
        // change our headers
        $headers = array( 
            $headers,
//          'Cc: Me <me@example.com>' ."\r\n", // INITIAL CODE
            'Cc: '.$cc_email.' <'.$cc_email.'>' ."\r\n", // MY CUSTOM CODE
    }
    return $headers;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'add_cc_to_certain_emails', 10, 2 );
```

I can't find the way to get custom user email from user meta data, and so my code doesn't work as expected.

How to get the custom user email from user meta data?

How to add this email (with the customer full name) as "CC" in email header?

Comment: You are missing a $user_id here.
The question is: Who´s user´s meta data 'order_cc_email' do you want to use?
The customer´s, the admin´s?

Comment: Yes thanks - how to add a $user_id? I've tried lots of different codes found on previous posts (including this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43814132/get-the-customer-id-from-an-order-id-in-woocommerce/43815280) but no success, I don't get how it works. The email is their accountant email that they indicate when they register their account (it's a B-to-B website) so the email is only available as a custom meta saved in the user page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some missing arguments in your hooked function, as `woocommerce_email_headers` filter hook allow 3 arguments:

- `$header` ===> the header data to be return in this filter
- `$email_id`==> the current `WC_Email` ID *(but not the `$object`…)*
- `$order` ====> the instance of the `WC_Order` object ***(the missing useful one)***

Try this revisited code instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'custom_cc_email_headers', 10, 3 );
function custom_cc_email_headers( $header, $email_id, $order ) {

    // Only for "Customer Completed Order" email notification
    if( 'customer_completed_order' !== $email_id )
        return $header;

    // Get the custom email from user meta data  (with the correct User ID)
    $custom_user_email = get_user_meta( $order->get_user_id(), 'order_cc_email', true );

    if( ! empty($custom_email) ) 
        return $header; // Exit (if empty value)

    // Get customer billing full name
    $user_name  = $order->get_billing_first_name().' ';
    $user_name .= $order->get_billing_last_name();

    // Merge and prepare the data
    $formatted_email = utf8_decode($user_name . ' <' . $custom_user_email . '>');

    // Add Cc to headers
    $header .= 'Cc: '.$formatted_email .'\r\n';

    return $header;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Related threads:

- [Get the customer ID from an order ID in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43814132/get-the-customer-id-from-an-order-id-in-woocommerce/43815280#43815280)
- [Adding custom emails to BCC for specific Woocommerce email notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49744010/adding-custom-emails-to-bcc-for-specific-woocommerce-email-notifications/49745070#49745070)

Answer (score 2):

I have modified the above code to include a second CC email address which is working for all notifications including a couple of custom emails I have set up, so thanks for the original code!

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'custom_cc_email_headers', 10, 3 );
function custom_cc_email_headers( $headers, $email_id, $order ) {

// Only for "Customer Completed Order" email notification
// if( 'wcj_custom_1' !== $email_id )
//    return $headers;

// Get the custom email from user meta data  (with the correct User ID)
$custom_user_email = get_user_meta( $order->get_user_id(), 'doc_email', true );
$bcc_email = get_user_meta( $order->get_user_id(), 'admin_email', true );

if( ! empty($custom_email) ) 
    return $headers; // Exit (if empty value)

// Get customer billing full name
$user_name  = $order->get_billing_first_name().' ';
$user_name .= $order->get_billing_last_name();

// Merge and prepare the data
$formatted_email = utf8_decode($user_name . ' <' . $custom_user_email . '>');
$formatted_email2 = utf8_decode($user_name . ' <' . $bcc_email . '>');

// Add Cc to headers
$headers .= 'Cc: '.$formatted_email ."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: '.$formatted_email2."\r\n";

return $headers;
}
```

I do have a couple of questions, why is the below var declared as

```
$custom_email
```

and not, in the if statement

```
$custom_user_email
```

Also, would it also be possible to make this into an array of email IDs to apply the cc addresses to?

```
// Only for "Customer Completed Order" email notification
// if( 'wcj_custom_1' !== $email_id )
//    return $headers;
```

As in as array like this (found [here](https://gist.github.com/ahmu83/e6e8aa2febc1b89f9ecb2deff6e4616b))

```
$email_ids = array(
   'new_order',
   'cancelled_order',
   'failed_order',
   'customer_on_hold_order',
   'customer_processing_order',
   'customer_completed_order',
   'customer_refunded_order',
   'customer_invoice',
   'customer_note',
   'customer_reset_password',
   'customer_new_account',
  );
```

I have tried to incorporate these ideas into the existing code, but failing to get it to work.