# I need to disable notification of a completed order for emails addresses that are specified in the billing email field woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to disable notification of a completed order for emails addresses that are specified in the billing email field in woocommerce.

how to do?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49785982/13378498 . In custom_user_email replace with the email you want.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate in your dashboard

Woocommerce > Settings, you will find the list of order types email.

Open up "Completed Order" and Disable the "
Enable/Disable", there you go.

If you are good with programming skills, go with
https://woocommerce.com/document/unhookremove-woocommerce-emails/